# Input from an array for awk to find duplicates

Tags: shell, awk, sh

I tried to input data for awk from an array:

```
awk -v var="${A[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(var,list,"\n"); for (i=1;i<=length(list);i++) print list[i]}'
```

Also using awk to find duplicates between files:

```
filecnt=$(find "${pmdir}" -type f)
awk -v  n=filecnt '{a[$0]++}END{for (i in a)if (a[i]>1){print i, a[i];}}' $filecnt  >> ${outputfile}
```

But I had hard time to find out how to do it if awk takes an array as its input.
something like:

```
awk -v var="${A[*]}" '{var[$0]++}END{for (i in var)if (var[i]>1){print i, var[i];}}'
```

A is a column data reading from a file:

```
for i in $( awk  -F ',' '{ print $1; }' "${ifile}" )
do
    A[$j]=$i
    #echo "${A[$j]}" 
    j=$((j+1))
done
```

example of A is

```
0x10000
0x11000
0x01100
0x00010
0x11000
0x00010
0x00010
```

The output is wanted:

```
0x11000 2
0x00010 3
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${A[@]}" | sort | uniq -cd | awk '{print $2, $1}'
0x00010 3
0x11000 2
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${A[@]}" | awk '{cnt[$0]++} END{for (val in cnt) if (cnt[val]>1) print val, cnt[val]}'
0x11000 2
0x00010 3
```

or:

```
$ awk -v vals="${A[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(vals,tmp); for (i in tmp) cnt[tmp[i]]++; for (val in cnt) if (cnt[val]>1) print val, cnt[val]}'
0x11000 2
0x00010 3
```

Note that that last one relies on none of the values in `A[]` containing spaces or escape chars.

Your `for` loop isn't how to populate `A[]` in the first place, though, this is:

```
A=()
while IFS= read -r i; do
    A+=( "$i" )
done < <(cut -d',' -f1 "$ifile")
```

or:

```
A=()
while IFS=',' read -r i _; do
    A+=( "$i" )
done < "$ifile"
```

or:

```
readarray -t A < <(cut -d',' -f1 "$ifile")
```

Comment: another version `... uniq -cd | awk '{print $2, $1}'`

Comment: @karakfa I'm shamelessly stealing that to improve my answer, thanks!

Comment: By the way, since it is mentioned above, I got ''syntax error '(' unexpected, if I have "A=()" or A+=("$i")" in my script. Not sure if it is because my version of shell is old.  Thanks.

Comment: idk, add a shebang to your script and copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you.